# Parameter continuity Rolle's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f$ be a function a $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function such that for all $x_2,...,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(.,x_2,...,x_n)$ goes to zero at infinity. By Rolle's theorem there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\partial_1f(y,x_2,...,x_n)=0$.
The thing is that $y$ depends on $x_2,...,x_n$, is there a technique to show that $\varphi:x_2,...,x_n\mapsto y$ is continuous ?

It would be first necessary to have a procedure to select $y$ uniquely so that $\varphi$ is  well-defined and then show that it is continuous (maybe by implicit function theorem).

Thanks!

Comment: A function has to be well-defined to talk about its continuity.

Comment: Yes indeed this is part of the problem...

Comment: For any closed subset of $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ you can find a smooth function whose zero set is exactly $A$ and consequently you can find a smooth function whose partial derivative with respect to the first coordinate has zeros exactly at $A$. Thus, in general it cannot be possible to find a continuous $\phi$ because for that the set $A$ has to be connected at the very least.